# button disabled not working properly angular

Tags: angular, angular8

Here is my scenario, where I have a date picker and a save button.

I am disabling the save button when the **date is not available**. Actually my code is working in general scenario

Here is my current code:

```js
disableDate() {
for (let index = 0; index < this.dataSource.data.length; index++) {
  if (this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].dob != '' && this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].dob != null
    && this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].doe != '' && this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].doe != null
    && this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].dom != '' && this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].dom != null
  ) {
    if (this.formatDate(this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].dob) > this.formatDate(this.dataSource.data[index].detail[0].doe)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
   return false;
}
```

Here is my HTML code for disabling the button

```html
<button mat-raised-button class="mx-1" color="primary" (click)="saveLplv()"
  [disabled]="disableDate()">Save</button>
```

What I am doing wrong here; why disable button not working properly?

Comment: You should look into form validators. Putting a function in template like that is generally bad practice.

Comment: We need some more details here. What is not working? Is there an error? Is it always disabled? Is it always enabled? What do you mean by it "working in general scenario?"

Comment: Make sure it actually produces the expected behavior if you write `[disabled]="false"`. If it does, then it could be that there's a bug in disableDate(), in which case I recommend unit testing it

Comment: Instead of disabling the button, you should make use of validators. If you want a custom validator, you can use `AbstractControl`. Then, when you want to submit the form: `<form (submit)="saveLplv()"` it's enough to do a simple check `if (this.form.invalid)` and let the validators do the work for you

Answer (score 0):

**First** :
Return type of `disableDate` should be bool.

**Second**

I would recommend you make a variable like `disableBtn` initially assign it false value

```
 disableBtn: boolean = false
```

Then in the method where you are checking condition , change status of button to true/false according your case

Comment: Can you please provide some reference fir using like what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **false** return **null**. An attribute like disabled, readonly is removed from HTML element only if it's value is **null**.

Comment: for both i need to provide null?

or in the last return only i need to provide null

Comment: You can check this StackBlitz script for the same. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhqyz6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)